# Filtering not working in transcluded DOM content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am building two AngularJS (version 1.6.5) components and I am not able to get filtering working when I use transclusion.

The first component is a simple container which uses transclusion to populate a `<div>` content:

```
app.component('panelWithTitle', {
  template: '<div><h1>{{$ctrl.title}}</h1><div class="content" ng-transclude></div></div>',
  bindings: {
    title: '@'
  },
  require: 'title',
  transclude: true
});
```

The second component uses the container (`<panel-with-title>`) and feed it with a simple filtered (from an input field) list:

```
app.component('mainComponent', {
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.allItems = ["10", "100", "200", "42", "1337"];
    // Simple filter function (may be more complicated)
    $scope.filterFunc = function (item) {
      if (!$scope.filterValue) {
        // No value
        return true;
      }
      return item.indexOf($scope.filterValue) !== -1;
    };
  },
  template: '<panel-with-title title="MyTitle">'            // Replace by <div>
      + '<input type="text" ng-model="filterValue">'
      + '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in allItems | filter:filterFunc">{{item}}</li></ul>'
      + '</panel-with-title>'                               // Replace by </div>
});
```

In that state, the filtering is not working because `$scope.filterValue` is undefined. [Here is a demo Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F6cWjFZfvZnkrMjX9MbD). I noticed:

- The filtering is working if I do not use transclusion (for instance: if I replace the `<panel-with-title>` tags by simple `<div>` tags).
- In any case, `$scope.allItems` is correctly defined.

What did I make wrong to get it not working? Why `$scope.filterValue` is undefined while `$scope.allItems` IS defined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$scope.filterValue` always `undefined` and filter returns `true` because your template uses different scope.

So add `$root` to `filterValue` like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$root.filterValue">
```

and in component use `$scope.$parent.filterValue`:

```
return item.indexOf($scope.$parent.filterValue) !== -1;
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2KTyMacr2TTMmReVkYfz?p=preview)</kbd>

---

*BTW, nice question :)*

Comment: Thank you. It is working. :) But a diagram might be useful here. Why does I need to do this for `filterValue` and not for `allItems` (which is well defined if I use it in the filtering func)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write more code means (filterFunc function) then

You should connect this code to the model (ng-model="filterValue") for **direct filter via the model**.
Please find my below plunker link -

http://plnkr.co/edit/sp9XFUMXLdmSwESujMQD?p=preview

```
app.component('mainComponent', {
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.allItems = ["10", "100", "200", "42", "1337"];
  },
  template: '<panel-with-title title="MyTitle">'            // Replace by <div>
      + '<input type="text" ng-model="filterValue">'
      + '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in allItems | filter:filterValue">{{item}}</li></ul>'
      + '</panel-with-title>'                               // Replace by </div>
});
```

Comment: I know. Actually it is the reason why I added the "Simple filter function (may be more complicated)" comment. My real filtering function is less simple than this. :) Anyway thank you!